# Convert “world file” GIS for MapBox GL?

Tags: gis, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to display GIF image with a world file (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.2/general/topics/author_world_files.htm) on Mapbox gl. The image is  displayed but it looks like it was shifted couple of degrees up. The following are the setups I followed to calculate the coordinates

```
A:0.017971305190311    <- Horizontal Pixel Distribution (deg/width) (A)
D:0.000000000000000    <- X Rotation (D)
B:0.000000000000000    <- Y Rotation (B)
E:-0.017971305190311   <- Vertical Pixel Distribution (deg/height) (E)
C:-127.620375523875420 <- X Coordinate for the center of the top left pixel (C)
F:50.406626367301044   <- Y Coordinate for the center of the top left pixel (F)
```

Used the following equation to calculate the Lat/Long @ each corner

```
Xn = Ax + By + C
Yn = Dx + Ey + F  

[-127.62037552387542,50.406626367301044],
[-66.51793787681802,50.406626367301044],
[-66.51793787681802,21.652538062803444],
[-127.62037552387542,21.652538062803444]
```

The Image documentation state that it was created using standard geographic projection referenced to North American Datum 1983 (NAD83). Is there any other steps needed to be done to display the image correctly on the map  ?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you could provide a lot more information about what you're doing. What are A,B,C,D,E,F? What do you mean "standard geographic projection"? How are you displaying it on the map exactly?

Comment: i update the my question . I'm not sure either what Standard geo projection intitle

Comment: If your problem is to do with understanding how to manage the projection, you might do better at gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Btw you say the image looks as if it is "shifted a couple of degrees up". But one corner of it is not shifted, as it's exactly the input coordinates. So is the image stretched? Or are your input coordinates wrong?